2x8 2mm data connector name
OK, this is the last post I make I swear... I'm trying to reuse some parts of a server I've bought (Dell poweredge r720) and I've realized that the drives board needs one more connector to work (most likely, powering 3.3/5v to the drives).
This one is a 2x8 connector, with ~2mm distance between pins. I need the female connector, but the male one as well would be nice to have.
Note: the photo of the measure I did it precisely. I just put that there for the photo.
Thanks to all of you guys... Without you I'd just have a pile of e-scrap, and thanks to this I think I'll be able to reuse the server! <3





My Identiconn utility identifies that as a Amphenol Minitek 2mm with latch.

Female plug housing
Male PCB header


{Source: Digikey}

That website looks interesting... does it tell you the connector by uploading an image or something?

" by uploading an image or something?" I wish! One day maybe, thanks to AI. No, it's done by drilling down by selecting attributes.

It's a great little site but in all fairness it assumes that the user knows quite a bit about connector terminology. I tried to use it for this question even, but wasn't sure whether these are "low profile" W2B or "prismatic". This looks like the kind of connector which might work both as wire-to-board and board-to-board too.

@Lundin. Excellent feedback. Thank you.
